# systemd vs normal shell execution?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, python

I am trying to have a systemd service run a script at boot, and every x minutes. One of the steps in the script is to set up a VPN connection; this steps fails when run as a systemd service.

The service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run the checkvpn bash script

[Service]
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/checkvpn.sh
```

The timer file

```
[Unit]
Description=checkvpn service timer

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=60
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:00
Unit=checkvpn.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi

isVpnConnected() {
  if [[ $(cyberghostvpn --status) =~ "Wireguard connection found" ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

isDockerRunning() {
  if [[ $(docker ps) =~ "some-docker-image" ]]; then
    return 0
  else 
    return 1
  fi
}

if isVpnConnected; then
  if isDockerRunning; then
    echo "vpn and docker ok"
  else
    echo "vpn ok, but docker is not running, starting docker ..."
    docker-compose -f /home/davy/git/nookie-config/docker-compose.yaml up -d
  fi
else
  echo "vpn not ok, connecting ..."
  cyberghostvpn --traffic --wireguard --country-code ES --connect
  if isVpnConnected; then
    if isDockerRunning; then
      echo "vpn restored, but docker was still running without vpn"
    else
      echo "vpn fixed, restarting docker ..."
      docker-compose -f /home/davy/git/nookie-config/docker-compose.yaml up -d
    fi
  else
   echo "unable to fix vpn, stopping dockers ..."
   docker-compose -f /home/davy/git/nookie-config/docker-compose.yaml down
  fi
fi
```

The error I get:

```
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]:   File "cyberghostvpn.py", line 5, in <module>
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]:   File "configs/base.py", line 3, in <module>
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]:   File "configs/base.py", line 12, in BaseConfiguration
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
Feb 12 14:14:02 nookie checkvpn.sh[8490]: [8490] Failed to execute script cyberghostvpn
```

Apparently the cyberghost cli utility is written in python, and it fails at importing something. I assumed the systemd environment is different from my user environment, but I don't know in what way. I also tried providing the same path variable as the one in my user environment, but that did not solve anything.

Any ideas?

Output of davy@nookie:~$ sudo find / -name "cybergho*"

```
    /home/davy/cyberghostvpn-ubuntu-20.04-1.3.4
    /home/davy/cyberghostvpn-ubuntu-20.04-1.3.4/cyberghost
    /home/davy/cyberghostvpn-ubuntu-20.04-1.3.4/cyberghost/cyberghostvpn
    /home/davy/cyberghost
    find: ‘/proc/6687’: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/cyberghostvpn
    /usr/local/cyberghost
    /usr/local/cyberghost/cyberghostvpn
    /etc/wireguard/cyberghost.conf
```

Comment: How was `cyberghostvpn` installed?  Was it via `apt`/`pacman`/`pip`, `tar -x`, `make install`?  After seeing `/usr/local/` in the stack, I suspect a bit of dependency hell.

Comment: I followed this guide: https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020436274-How-to-Set-Up-CyberGhost-VPN-CLI-App-on-Linux

Comment: One difference could be who is calling it.  If `cyberghost` is expecting a graphical session, so it can place a little icon in your task-tray, then running as root could fail.  You can confirm this suspicious by trying to run the software as root (careful there).  If you don't want to (totally understandable), try adding `User=<you>`, `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=1m`.  That will cause `systemd` to run your software as **you** instead of as root. If that works, we can talk about a more elegant solution with the user bus and graphical-session.target.

Comment: its a command line tool, so i would assume it never expects a graphical session? Also, i am running ubuntyu server, so no graphical ui :) I will try your suggestions and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried the User= approach, but it does not work, the cyberghostvpn util NEEDS to run as root, otherwise it will not work

Comment: I would investigate line 12 of the `configs/base.py` file to see what is being concatenated. At least one of those values is apparently empty.

Comment: It is not a script of mine, it is a binary provided by vpn host. Can i decompile it?

Comment: @Davy They're not binaries, they are Python files presumably installed by Cyberghost's `install.sh` script. Do a search on your system for the file `cyberghostvpn.py`... the `configs/base.py` should be relative to its location. When you find it just open in a text editor and look at line 12.

Comment: No such file im afraid ... (executed sudo find / -name "cybergho*", nothing came up, output is in question)

Comment: What if you use `cron` for timing?

Comment: Hmm, apparently Cyberghost likes to keep their utilities and helper scripts well-hidden from users. Besides being closed-source it is also paywalled, so maybe you would have better luck contacting their customer service. The only other thing I could suggest is looking in the `checkvpn.sh` script and see if there's some clues there about how it's calling those Python files.

Comment: Despite being bountied, it will be hard to resolve a installation problem around closed-source software.  Best to contact the developer.

Comment: Tried that. They were not really helpful (which i can understand, they cant help everyone who has problems with a script)

Comment: Just to make it clear: the checkvpn script is mine.

Comment: I can't say I understand the problem fully, but since you mention environmental differences as a possible cause, perhaps their support line can tell you which environment variables are critical to the application?

Comment: @Davy I would try asking customer support where the `cyberghostvpn.py` and `configs/base.py` files can be found. Maybe they will answer that. Also, you can see environment variables with the `printenv` command, if you want to know `systemd`'s environment, have your `.service` file run a script containing the command `printenv > /tmp/systemdenv`.

Comment: If the devs are going to release closed-source material, they HAVE to support everyone with a problem.  Otherwise they haven't delivered what you bought.  Now it's in their interest to reduce the workload on themselves. To do that they could choose to make their scripts more robust, so if a problem does happen, a user-readable message is printed instead of a `TypeError` exception with a call stack.

Answer (score 1):

> I assumed the systemd environment is different from my user environment but i dont know in what way.

You could find out with a (very) short script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
printenv > /home/davy/environment_"$( date +%s )"
```

The script executes the `printenv` command, which lists all environment variables, then saves the output to `/home/davy/environment_xxxxxxxxxx`, where the *`xxxxxxxxxx`* part of the filename is the current Unix timestamp in seconds (the only reason I picked this peculiar file name is so the file won't be overwritten each time the script is executed, but the name and save location can obviously be changed to whatever you like).

Have a `systemd.service` execute this script so you can compare the resulting file to the one produced when you execute the same script in a shell using `sudo`. This difference between these two files will tell you which environment variables are absent in `systemd`.

It's a longshot and I'd be amazed if it works, but you can try creating a file `Vars` (or whatever name you want to give it) that lists only the variables (one per line, formatted the exact same way as output by `printenv`) that were present with `sudo` but absent in `systemd`, then changing the `Environment=PATH=...` line in your `.service` file to `EnvironmentFile=/path/to/Vars`, then restart the service with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

FWIW, I found one other mention of the exact same Python errors when a user was trying to automate Cyberghost using `cron` and he was able get it to work in a way I'm not sure I understand nor can I vouch for, but perhaps you will have better luck:

https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2060369 (French)

([English translation](https://forum-ubuntu--fr-org.translate.goog/viewtopic.php?id=2060369&_x_tr_sl=fr&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc))

Comment: i will give this a try

Comment: Well, be amazed because it worked ;) I created a file using the printenv command, specified it in the EnvironmentFile parameter in my systemd unit, and voila, no more errors. Thank you!

Comment: @Davy I'm delighted to hear it worked!